# fetching value while date is greater than another date

Tags: date, codeigniter-3

My `$_POST['date']==01-2017` and `$_POST['mon']==11-2016` and when i use my code to compare greater than function like this

```
if(date($_POST['date'])>date($_POST['mon']))
   {
    $data['f']=$this->admin_model->ajax_f();
    $data['fine']='';
   }
```

only the first values of both the post values are considering that means only `01` and `11` is considering not the entire value.

Comment: hello..anybody have any idea

Comment: Why are you not using full date format including day,month,year? If you are using full date format, you can use strtotime()

Comment: the concept is like that that means the amount of the month($_POST['mon'] and the amount to be paid of the month($_POST['date']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the dates to epoch times/unix timestamps then compare:

```
// field [0] is month, field [1] is year
$date_tmp = explode("-", $_POST['date']);
$mon_tmp = explode("-", $_POST['mon']);

// create epoch times
$date_secs = mktime(0,0,0,$date_tmp[0],0,$date_tmp[1]);
$mon_secs = mktime(0,0,0,$mon_tmp[0],0,$mon_tmp[1]);

if($date_secs > $mon_secs)
{
    $data['f']=$this->admin_model->ajax_f();
    $data['fine']='';
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 2):

Something even simpler... maybe, with all the caveats on ensuring the post values are present and of the correct format...

```
$post_date = strtotime('00-' . $_POST['date']);
$post_mon  = strtotime('00-' . $_POST['mon']);
if($post_date > $post_mon) {
    $data['f']=$this->admin_model->ajax_f();
    $data['fine']='';
}
```